# "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies But ..." MVC issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ive really searched all over the web and im just stack on this problem.. pls help :( (new with MVC)
when im trying to run a specific page , im getting the message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Category_B85D1A3F838C0192719C683B1095328267C570F7A660F0D', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Leeoriyas.Models.Category'.

my controller "storecontroller" (the relevent part)

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Leeoriyas.Models;

    namespace Leeoriyas.Controllers

public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        LeeoriyasFPEntities storeDB = new LeeoriyasFPEntities();
        // GET: Store


     public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(storeDB.Category.ToList());
            }
 public ActionResult Browse(string Category)
        {
            var categoryModel = storeDB.Category.Include("ArtS").Single(c => c.Name == Category);
                return View(categoryModel);
        }
```

my view (browse)

```
@model Leeoriyas.Models.Category


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browsing category: @Model.Name</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var product in Model.ArtS)
    {
        <li>
            @product.Title
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

thanks!! :(

Comment: You are send the parameter Category for page ex: http://yourdomain/Store/Browser/{category}?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending what is expected to your view. You specify a type of `Leeoriyas.Models.Category`, so ensure that you are passing an object of that kind. You should pass something like this:

```
 public ActionResult Browse(string category)
        {
            Leeoriyas.Models.Category categoryModel = storeDB.Category.Include("ArtS").Single(c => c.Name == category);
                return View(categoryModel);
        }
```

Ensure that the return of this line `storeDB.Category.Include("ArtS").Single(c => c.Name == category);` is of type Category

Comment: it says that it cant convert type of leeoriyas.category to Leeoriyas.Models.Category :(

Comment: you have to write your object translator to convert your db entity to dto type

Comment: It says that your view is expecting Leeoriyas.Models.Category but getting System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Category_B85D1A3F838C0192719C683B1095328267C570F7A660F0D instead. You have to fix that.

Comment: yeah but how should i do that ?

Comment: be sure to return a object of the type Categoty, or else you can remove the strong type of your view (@model Leeoriyas.Models.Category) and return a var like you are doing.

Comment: i removed it and it gives me a comiplation error